# Activity.findViewById() error "expected resource of type id" on R.layout object

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

I'm following this online tutorial to build a part of my app that will return a list of my contacts, but I've run in to a bit of an issue that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the tutorial.

This is in the class `ContactsFragment`, which is not the main activity of the project but returns the fragment for the main activity to use.

The error is occurring here...

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mContactsList =
        (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view); <--- here
    //...
}
```

The error reads "expected resource of type id", which is strange because Android Studio's intellisense is suggesting `contacts_list_view` to me when writing the code.

`contacts_list_view.xml` is a file in the `res/layout` directory that I have copied from the tutorial. Its contents is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and Android development in general, so there's a chance I'm missing something obvious. Feel free to point that out to me, or anything else that might fix my issue!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` in this case

Comment: The [r] tag is for the R programming language. Don't use it to tag problems with R files

Comment: @Dason my sincerest apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in the code:

`(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);` for `(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);`

And in the .xml file:

`android:id="@android:id/list"` for `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea why this was displayed wrongly in the tutorial? Is this an older way of handling it?

Answer (score 0):

You call `findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);` with the param `R.layout.contacts_list_view` but what you need there is an id of a view...what you need actually there is `R.id.list`

Answer (score 0):

Try using, the warning will gone

```
setContentView(R.id.main_layout as Int)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just `initialize` in inside `OnViewCreated` like this

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       ListView mContactsList =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
    }
```